# How can I write a case that excludes a certain input parameter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parameters, functional-programming, tuples

In Haskell how can I write:

```
function :: (Int,Int) ....
function Not(0,0) otherparameters = []
```

i.e I have a function where in want to return an empty list for every case except when the first argument is the tuple (0,0)

How is it possible to do this in Haskell ?

I have tried function (not (0,0)) but got the following error

```
Parse error in pattern: not
```

Many thanks

Comment: Try using a guard instead of a pattern match

Answer (score 8):

Write the exceptional pattern first:

```
function :: (Int,Int) ....
function (0,0) otherParameters = exceptionalResult
function _     _               = [] -- empty list in every other case
```

Comment: And if the function isn't supposed to be defined *at all* for `(0, 0)`, return `undefined` explicity.